# Access props of imported component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How could I pass/access the props of an imported component? This example component comes from a third-party library, so I'm not sure how I'd go about getting its props

```
import { Example } from './comps' 
    
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Example />
  );
  console.log(Example.props) //this returns undefined 
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access props of a child Component from parent Component in that way.
Moreover:

```
const App = () => {
  return ( // return will finish the function, so the console.log below doesn't make any sense.
    <Example />
  );
  console.log(Example.props) //this returns undefined 
}
```

In your example, props is the things passed from `App`, so you can pass/access directly from `App`:

```
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  return (
    <Example number={value} setNumber={setValue} />
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I guess I'm getting a bit confused between props and state. I'm trying to get the state of a specific prop from the imported component so I can reference it in App. I suppose I'll need to pass the state from the imported component into the App...?

Comment: Yes you can, but it takes time. You'll need to use `useEffect` in `Example` to set the  props to `App` as the way `setNumber={setValue}` in my example did.